# What is wrong with this query with nested IN clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get data from a MySQL table using this query. But it's taking forever to run. I think there is something wring with the query itself and the nested `IN` I used. Is there an optimal way to run this query?

```
SELECT * FROM xf_attachment_data WHERE data_id IN (
    SELECT data_id FROM xf_attachment WHERE content_id IN (
        SELECT field_value FROM xf_user_field_value WHERE field_id = 'medicalid' AND field_value <> ''
    )
)
```

Comment: `<>` ==> `!=` (I think)

Comment: @AlonEitan `<>` is the ansi sql one, `!=` is the mysql's extention. The former should be actually preferred.

Comment: Can you please show some data in those tables what you have and what you are trying to achieve. The outcome of the query yoy want to have

Comment: MySQL seems to be exceptionally slow on nested sub-queries.  Rewrite it using joins and it should be much faster!

Comment: You should really have posted the schema and stats.

Comment: please show schemas of these tables..

Answer (score 0):

try with joins instead:

```
SELECT xad.* 
FROM xf_attachment_data AS xad
LEFT JOIN xf_attachment AS xa
  ON xad.data_id = xa.data_id
LEFT JOIN xf_user_field_value AS xufv
  ON xa.content_id = xufv.field_value -- from your original query
WHERE xufv.field_id = 'medicalid' 
  AND xufv.field_value <> ''
```

With this kind of construct optimization can do a better job, and `EXPLAIN`would give you better insight about how to make it run faster, which indexes would be useful, and so on.

BTW, column names in your inner query seem a bit odd, are you sure you want to compare xf_attachment.content_id with xf_user_field_value.field_value?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know really if its optimal or not.  But you can try this:

```
Select * from xf_attachment_data AD,  xf_attachment A, xf_user_field_value FV where AD. Data_id = A.data_id and A.content_id = FV.field_value and field_id = 'medicalid' AND field_value <> '';
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest rewriting this using `EXISTS` rather than `in`, because MySQL sometimes does a better job with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ad.* 
ROM xf_attachment_data ad
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM xf_attachment a
              WHERE a.data_id = ad.data_id AND
                    EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM xf_user_field_value fv
                            WHERE fv.field_id = 'medicalid' AND
                                  a.content_id = fv.field_value
                           )
              );
```

Then, be sure you have the right indexes:  `xf_user_field_value(field_value, field_id)` and `xf_attachment(data_id, content_id)`.

You might consider rewriting this as `join`s.  However, if there are duplicate records, this nested approach might have better performance.